# How to understand a parameter in function?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def add_me_up(self,more):
    self.number += more
    return self.number
```

As I understand,

- `more` is parameter `for add_me_up()`
- `self.number += more` is the same as `self.number=self.number + more`

But I still do not understand how it works. Please explain.
(this section is from the book Learn Python the Hard Way).

Comment: [Learn Python the Not So Hard Way](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python)

Answer (score 0):

'more' is just a variable. You assign any value you want to it and then call the add_me_up function, passing the 'more' variable as the only parameter. The self object retains the cumulative total after each calls to the function add_me_up .

Comment: what's the default value for 'more'?

Comment: It has no default, you need to give a value such as more = 4. Then say your_object.add_me(more) to  add 4 to the objects total.

Comment: humm...in my idea it should has a value,but it works in following code,class TheThing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number=0
    def some_function(self):
        print"i got called."
    def add_me_up(self,more):
        self.number += more
        return self.number  print a.add_me_up(20)

Comment: i searched and understood that self is an instance of class, which do not need passing value to it, so the value 20 passes to more, so it works, thanks for your answer KIM :)

Comment: Glad to help. Would appreciate it if you could give some points for the answer.